# Resample Raster in PyQGIS with Median Approach

Tags: raster, pyqgis, resolution

I have a raster file with a spatial resolution of 2m x 2m. I want to resample the raster from a 2m by 2m resolution to a 25m by 25m resolution in PyQGIS.
My approach is using the Nearest Neightbour to determine, what raster value the resulting 20m x 20m cell has. I use the warpreproject function from gdal (I am aware, that this is originally used to reproject into another CRS):

```
input_raster= QgsRasterLayer("/path/to/raster.tif", "rasterX)                
processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", {'INPUT':input_raster,'SOURCE_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2056'),'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2056'),'RESAMPLING':0,'NODATA':None,'TARGET_RESOLUTION':20,'OPTIONS':'','DATA_TYPE':0,'TARGET_EXTE`enter code here`NT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'EXTRA':'','OUTPUT':output})
```

**I want to resample the raster from a 2m by 2m raster to a 20m by 20m raster with the MEDIAN Approach, not the Nearest Neighbour Approach.** How can I do this in PyQGIS? I have seen, that there is QgsRasterResamplerV2(input_raster) and other pipes, but I did not find any examples, how to resample a raster image.

Comment: `processing.run("grass7:r.resamp.stats", {'input':'/path/to/raster.tif','method':1, 'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':20, rest of args can be figured out by running manually on your data})` The `'method':1` means median.

Comment: Thank you @user2856. I will try it out this evening.

Comment: @user2856 It worked, thank you. I didn't know that grass7 was avaiable in QGIS. I will edit the question and add a general solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @user2865 the "grass7:r.resamp.stats" module will resample the raster to the desired resolution.

```
        processing.run("grass7:r.resamp.stats", {'input':'/path/to/raster.tif','method':1,'quantile':0.5,'-n':False,'-w':False,'output':output,'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':20,'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'','GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''})
```

where Method 1 is the median approach. The full description can be seen in the r.resamp.stats GRASS GIS manual: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/r.resamp.stats.html